# Simple Line Graph in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

How can I make a graph with this data:

```
Club    distance    club speed
9 iron  85.8            71.7
9 iron  89.8            68.6
9 iron  85.2            69
5 iron  132.5           73.6
5 iron  131.3           74.8
5 iron  146.5           74.2
Driver  188             84.6
Driver  196.1           85.3
Driver  186.6           85.4
```

So that the Distance is on the Y-axis and the Speed is on the X-axis?

Comment: Which version of excel are you using? And how do you want to include the information as to which club you're using?

Comment: Oops, nevermind, didn't see the tag

Comment: I want each club 9 iron, 5 iron and driver to have 1 continuous line over speed by distance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, to make a line graph of that information, click `Insert` at the top to bring up the Insert ribbon. Select the `Distance` data, then on the Insert ribbon, click on the `Line` button and choose the one you want, probably the first one. The chart should appear. Then, right click on the chart and choose `Select Data`.  In the window that appears, click `Edit` on the right side under the heading `Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels`. Another box will pop up. Select your `Speed` data and press `OK`, then press `OK` again on the `Select Data Source` window, and your graph should be set up.

Comment: That makes a graph like this: http://gyazo.com/bea897b1e0fe6404507b8ae1f4d89e7e

Comment: Looks like it created a separate series for each data point. Right click and edit data again, then on the left, delete all the series except one. Select that one, click edit, then select your Distance data and hit OK.

Answer (score 1):

`Insert - scatter plot` and clear it out.
Right click `select data - add` and for each point have `series name = club` `series x values = speed` and `series y values = distance` and plot each point as a series

[image]